# Android build and distribute to GooglePlayConsole URLs list for allow traffic whitelist

Tags: android, gradle, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

I am currently facing an issue with my Android project that utilizes Gradle. When attempting to build the project, it seems to be making requests to various IP addresses, which are dynamically changing. Our company's security team is actively managing and restricting access based on URLs (CNAME), and they have requested a list of all the URLs that need to be allowed for this traffic.

Could you please provide me with the comprehensive list of URLs that are essential for the build and distribute to Google Play process? This information will help our information security team in configuring the necessary access permissions.

i need whitelist URL!

Thank you for your assistance.